# ¿Cómo evitar que otro usuario no actualice o borre un POST a un perfil que no le corresponde?

Tags: python, django

¿Cómo puedo evitar que un usuario modifique un post que no le corresponde a él?

Ejemplo: un usuario entra a: `www.localhost:8080/perfil/emergencia/update/1` <-- evitar que los post autoincrementales que tenga la base de datos (el modelo) no puedo modificar a uno que no le corresponda a él.

Ejemplo de una vista que tengo:

**view.py**

```
def EmergenciaUpdate(request, emergencia_id):
     instancia = get_object_or_404(Emergencia,id=emergencia_id)
     form = EmergenciaUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=instancia)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('emergencialista')
     return render(request, 'app/emergenciaupdate.html', {'emergencia_update_form':form})
```

**url.py**

```
url(r'^perfil/numero/emergencia/update/(?P<emergencia_id>\d+)/$', EmergenciaUpdate, name='emergenciaupdate'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Emergencia(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nombre_emergencia = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    tel_emergencia = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

Uso por defecto el modelo de usuario de Django.

Comment: Hola. ¿Cómo sabes si le corresponde o no? Asumo que en el modelo tienes una relación con el usuario. Prefiero no adivinar y esperar a que incluyas tu modelo en la pregunta.

Comment: Sí hay una relación. Editado con el modelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues, es muy sencillo, solo tienes que comparar el usuario logueado (`request.user`) con el usuario de tu instancia. Tal vez lo que puedas hacer es simplemente redirigir a otro lado:

```
def EmergenciaUpdate(request, emergencia_id):
     instancia = get_object_or_404(Emergencia,id=emergencia_id)

     if request.user != instancia.usuario:
         return redirect('algún lado')    

     form = EmergenciaUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=instancia)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('emergencialista')
     return render(request, 'app/emergenciaupdate.html', {'emergencia_update_form':form})
```

Aunque tal vez una forma más elegante es hacerle pensar al usuario que esa instancia no existe levantando un 404:

```
from django.http import Http404


def EmergenciaUpdate(request, emergencia_id):
     instancia = get_object_or_404(Emergencia,id=emergencia_id)

     if request.user != instancia.usuario:
         raise Http404()    

     form = EmergenciaUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=instancia)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('emergencialista')
     return render(request, 'app/emergenciaupdate.html', {'emergencia_update_form':form})
```

Comment: Gracias. Funciona.

Comment: @CLG si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada. De otra forma tu pregunta se queda abierta (sin solución). Saludos.